# A dice containing the numbers 1 to 10 is rolled $n$ times such that the probability that 1 to 5 are all rolled at least once is $50 \%$. What is $n$?

Tags: probability, statistics

With $n=5$ and $n=6$ the probability is $0.0012$ and $0.0054$ respectively, the difficulty arises when I try to solve for higher numbers of $n$. I solved above by $\frac{5!}{10^5}$ and $\frac{5 \cdot \frac{6!}{2}+5 \cdot 6!}{10^6}$ which isn't or at least not a really obvious closed form. A closed form and its derivation in terms of $n$ (if it exists) would be better though than choosing $n$ that reaches the $50 \%$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $i=1,2,3,4,5$ let $E_i$ denote the event that face $i$ is **not** rolled in $n$ times.

Applying inclusion/exclusion and symmetry we find:
$$P\left(E_{1}^{\complement}\cap E_{2}^{\complement}\cap E_{3}^{\complement}\cap E_{4}^{\complement}\cap E_{5}^{\complement}\right)=1-P\left(E_{1}\cup E_{2}\cup E_{3}\cup E_{4}\cup E_{5}\right)=$$$$\sum_{k=0}^{5}\binom{5}{k}\left(-1\right)^{k}P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{k}E_{i}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{5}\binom{5}{k}\left(-1\right)^{k}\left(1-\frac{k}{10}\right)^{n}$$

(Substituting $n=5$ and $n=6$ you will find $0.0012$ and $0.0054$ respectively)

---

**Edit**: explicit answer to the question in the title is $n=21$ (see comments on this answer).

Comment: (+1) Here's Wolfram Alpha results for [$n=20$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%285+choose+k%29*%28-1%29%5Ek*%281-k%2F10%29%5En%2C+k+from+0+to+5%2C+n%3D20) and [$n=21$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%285+choose+k%29*%28-1%29%5Ek*%281-k%2F10%29%5En%2C+k+from+0+to+5%2C+n%3D21).

Comment: @NeatMath Yes, thank you. I just found in excel that $n=21$ is the first with $>0.5$.

Comment: Yes, thank you! This is what I'm looking for. Substituting, $n=21$ is indeed the answer. The inclusion and exclusion of events is very helpful for understanding the closed form, thanks!

Comment: You are very welcome. There is a possibility for you to accept the answer.